How to set back file ownership from a reference (/etc) directory to a copy on Linux?
Context :

Debian 12 system recovery trial after a btrfs file system corruption (roots tree) with no backup but access to all(?) the files. I made a copy of the system after the corruption, everything looks right. I made a fresh install of Debian 12. From here, I have rsynced the system, except /etc . For this last one, I have rsynced only missing files.
Now, I have to update smartly /etc. I want to use tools like meld to make it easier. But it does not work as root. So I made copies of previous and new /etc and chown -R user:user both from a LIVE DVD.

When my new etc is updated, I want to restore files/directories ownership before replacing the whole /etc of the new install.
The subject here is not my system restoration, but file ownership restoration from a copy of the tree that has the same files and right ownerships.
ls -l provides ownership but not full paths. find provides full paths but not ownership. I have eventually found this solution:
find previous_etc -exec sh -c 'chown -v --reference=$0 "new_etc${0#previous_etc}"' {}  \;

So, this is a self answered question. But if you have other methods, I am curious.

Please post your answer as an answer  and remove it from the question.

ok, as soon as authorized

mtree is designed exactly for this use case.
Let's assume you have your files in etc:
# cd /
# find etc -ls
553527   1 drwxr-xr-x    2 root    wheel       7 May  8 11:23 etc
553434   1 -rw-------    1 nobody  wheel      29 May  8 11:23 etc/baz
553214   1 -rwxr-xr-x    1 jim     wheel      29 May  8 11:23 etc/foo
553433   1 -rw-------    1 jim     wheel      29 May  8 11:23 etc/stuff
553431   1 -rw-------    1 root    nogroup    29 May  8 11:23 etc/bar
553432   1 -rw-------    1 uucp    wheel      29 May  8 11:23 etc/farkle

And you have a copy of the files, but with incorrect ownership and permissions in etc.new:
# find etc.new -ls
555768   1 drwx--x---    2 jim     jim         7 May  8 11:23 etc.new
555771   1 -rwxrwxrwx    1 jim     jim        29 May  8 11:23 etc.new/stuff
555772   1 -rwxrwxrwx    1 jim     jim        29 May  8 11:23 etc.new/bar
555769   1 -rwxrwxrwx    1 jim     jim        29 May  8 11:23 etc.new/baz
555773   1 -rwxrwxrwx    1 jim     jim        29 May  8 11:23 etc.new/farkle
555770   1 -rwxrwxrwx    1 jim     jim        29 May  8 11:23 etc.new/foo

On the left side of this pipe, we -c "Create" an mtree specification for -p
"Path" etc, while on the right, we read that specification on stdin and
compare it to the file hierarchy in path etc.new.  Mtree tells us that
many files "should be" (first value) but actually are (second value):
# mtree -cp etc | mtree -p etc.new
.:      user (0, 1001)
        gid (0, 1001)
        permissions (0755, 0710)
stuff:  gid (0, 1001)
        permissions (0600, 0777)
bar:    user (0, 1001)
        gid (65533, 1001)
        permissions (0600, 0777)
baz:    user (65534, 1001)
        gid (0, 1001)
        permissions (0600, 0777)
farkle: user (66, 1001)
        gid (0, 1001)
        permissions (0600, 0777)
foo:    gid (0, 1001)
        permissions (0755, 0777)

On the right side of the pipe, if we add the -u "Update" flag, mtree will
actually make the change so the the ownership and permissions of files in
etc.new get set so they match the reference files in etc:
# mtree -cp etc | mtree -up etc.new
.:      user (0, 1001, modified)
        gid (0, 1001, modified)
        permissions (0755, 0710, modified)
stuff:  gid (0, 1001, modified)
        permissions (0600, 0777, modified)
bar:    user (0, 1001, modified)
        gid (65533, 1001, modified)
        permissions (0600, 0777, modified)
baz:    user (65534, 1001, modified)
        gid (0, 1001, modified)
        permissions (0600, 0777, modified)
farkle: user (66, 1001, modified)
        gid (0, 1001, modified)
        permissions (0600, 0777, modified)
foo:    gid (0, 1001, modified)
        permissions (0755, 0777, modified)

And indeed, find etc etc.new -ls confirms that they are now identical:
# find etc etc.new -ls
553527   1 drwxr-xr-x    2 root    wheel       7 May  8 11:23 etc
553434   1 -rw-------    1 nobody  wheel      29 May  8 11:23 etc/baz
553214   1 -rwxr-xr-x    1 jim     wheel      29 May  8 11:23 etc/foo
553433   1 -rw-------    1 jim     wheel      29 May  8 11:23 etc/stuff
553431   1 -rw-------    1 root    nogroup    29 May  8 11:23 etc/bar
553432   1 -rw-------    1 uucp    wheel      29 May  8 11:23 etc/farkle
555768   1 drwxr-xr-x    2 root    wheel       7 May  8 11:23 etc.new
555771   1 -rw-------    1 jim     wheel      29 May  8 11:23 etc.new/stuff
555772   1 -rw-------    1 root    nogroup    29 May  8 11:23 etc.new/bar
555769   1 -rw-------    1 nobody  wheel      29 May  8 11:23 etc.new/baz
555773   1 -rw-------    1 uucp    wheel      29 May  8 11:23 etc.new/farkle
555770   1 -rwxr-xr-x    1 jim     wheel      29 May  8 11:23 etc.new/foo

